# Decrypting Spring property values In Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

Docker 1.12.1

Spring-Boot 1.3.2

I'm "dockerizing" my spring-boot application which has sensitive data in the .yml file. I don't want to have this content stored in plain text. But when the application starts up in Docker it will need to be able to access the decrypted (plain text) version of the values so the values can be used with `@Value` in the application.

I found this [link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) from spring cloud but its not really clear how I would get encrypting/decryption working in a local way, let alone how it would all work when introducting docker.

My questions are this

1. How would I go about encrypting the sensitive text in a way that will allow it to be decrypted when ran in Docker.
2. How would I go about decrypting the text so when the application starts up in docker the decrypted values are used or even when starting the application locally the decrypted values are used?

Comment: How are you currently decrypting it? Why can't that process happen within the container?

Comment: Because of this challenge my team actually doesnt run the application locally. However in dev, qa, and prod we are using spring cloud server to decrypt. Spring cloud does the decryption on the fly when returning the value to the application. I'm wondering if i should dockerize a spring cloud instance also

Comment: There are strong arguments against putting Docker into prod (feel free to read up on that). Anyways, I can't guide you on Spring things, just don't really see the use case of containerizing anything other than "because we can"

Comment: @cricket_007 docker will not be used in prod at all. The use case is for simplicity when pulling serval dozen microservices together and running in one environement lets say for testing them all together. These services are build by serval different companies. so if all things are dockerized you can spin these applications up as needed anywhere. In my cases ive only found docker to be useful in testing scenarios not saying thats the only thing probably other valid use cases as well.

Comment: when ran without docker, where are the encrypted files stored ? in git ?

Comment: Your docker image could pull the git repo, and your spring cloud server config could be set to use the local repository. Thus, you'd still be able to use the spring cloud decryption within your container.

Comment: @Alex i'm thinking i can just save a local copy of the properties in the application and have spring cloud decrypt that. Guess this means i will also need to run an instance of spring cloud in parallel with my application in this container

Comment: I would do that too. By "keeping a copy", you mean "git clone" ?

Answer (score 0):

1. jasypt-spring-boot-starter to encrypt your content
2. For encrypt key, use maven properties like @secret.key@
3. Pass the secret.key with -Dsecret.key=xxx when you build your spring from command line, then build docker image
4. Make sure necessary people could access your container to view the secret.key. Protect your secret.key.